# How is Google bolding the word that is searched for in the description?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a very similar search function to how Google search function works, where if you google a word it is bolded in the returned search data.

[image]

For my search engine, the searched word is stored in this span:

```
<span class="searchResults-term">Lorem</span>
```

Where Lorem is the word the user would type in the input field. My input field is very simple:

```
<input type="text">
```

The search description is displayed from within this div:

```
<div class="searchResults-result"> 
   <h3 class="searchResults-title">Lorem Ipsum 
   </h3> 
</div>
```

How can I highlight the word Lorem in the search description if the user typed in lorem in the input field or highlight Ipsum if the user typed in ipsum in the input field? This must also not be case sensitive.

I am so stuck on this for hours and been researching for a whole day. Please any help would be great. Thanks!

I have been writing jquery but I don't think the set up for it is correct.

```
var oldSRTerm = $(".span.searchResults-term").val();

newSRTerm = '<span class="add-pink-bg">' + $(".span.searchResults-term").val() + '</span>',

newSRDesc = $('.searchResults-description').val().replace(RegExp(oldSRTerm,"gi"),newSRTerm);

$('.searchResults-description').html(newSRDesc);
```

Comment: When an user search some text first you have to access that text in a variable then use this `variable_name.bold();`

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment, and I am not an expert with JQuery but hopefully my answer is helpful enough:

In order to eleiminate case usage you can use .**toLowerCase()** method.

Add logic that **if** the user's input.toLowerCase() is === matchingInput.toLowerCase()

The text should be bold by manipulating the style of the font. Ex:

```
$matchingInput.css("font-weight","Bold")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

What I realize is that you're trying to replace the `.val()` of your descriptions which is incorrect as `.val()` is used for `input`, 'select`, other form elements only. What you need to do is get the "text" of your description first then do replace on that.

```
var content = $description.html().trim();
```

or

```
var content = $description.text().trim();
```

**Note**: last time I used `.text()` it wasn't widely supported but that was a while ago.

#### Other notes:

What you can do is actually add the wrapper in within `.replace` with `RegExp` returning the value, this is done by wrapping the search term in `()`:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(" + searchTerm + ")");

content = content.replace(RegExp(regex, 'gi'), '<span class="searchResults-description-highlight">$1</span>');
```

Here is it working: https://jsfiddle.net/tx4nysmk/3/